# Authentication with Devise in Rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I'm having trouble getting my Rspec tests to run correctly on items where Devise is trying to authenticate a user in a before_filter.

I followed the example from the Devise Git wiki: [How To: Controllers and Views tests with Rails 3 (and rspec)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29)

spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
   config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
   config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
   config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
   config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

spec/support/controller_macros.rb:

```
 module ControllerMacros
   def login_user
     before(:each) do
       @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
       user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
       sign_in user
     end
   end
 end
```

spec/controllers/test.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe ProjectsController do
  def valid_attributes
    {
    :name         => 'Project',
    :description  => 'Description'
    }
  end

  def valid_session
    {}
  end

  describe "Test" do

    login_user

    it "assigns all projects as @projects" do
      # test passes if the following line is here, otherwise fails
      subject.current_user.should_not be_nil

      project = Project.create! valid_attributes
      get :index, {}, valid_session
      assigns(:projects).should eq([project])
    end
  end
end
```

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb (straight from generator except for addition of a before filter:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = Project.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @projects }
    end
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  # GET /projects/new.json
  def new
    @project = Project.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /projects/1
  # PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

Why does the test pass with the inclusion of `subject.current_user.should_not be_nil` but fails when it is not included?

Comment: Wiki link is now: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29

Comment: Now the page referenced in @littleforest's comment is https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-(and-RSpec)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when following [the how-to you mention](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29). The solution is to remove calls to `valid_session` from each of the requests, since it overrides the session values set by the `sign_in` helper.

It's actually documented in a code-block in the very same how-to, I missed it too :(

Comment: Man, you should win a medal!